# How to select specific characters from input in R?

Tags: r, select, text, substring

I have a vector with data of the form

```
c("AM1-Project", "AM14-Blend", "B5-Implement", "SS10-Review")
```

and I would like to select only the characters until "-", so the ouptut should be

```
c("AM1", "AM14", "B5", "SS10")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `sub` here:

```r
x <- c("AM1-Project", "AM14-Blend", "B5-Implement", "SS10-Review")
output <- sub("-.*", "", x)
output

[1] "AM1"  "AM14" "B5"   "SS10"
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you also know how I can choose the characters until the number ex. "AM", "B", "SS"?

Comment: Use: `sub("\\d*-.*", "", x)`